# How to resolve custom nested graphql query with Apollo CacheRedirects

Tags: apollo, apollo-client

We are using apollo-client in a react project. We made a cursor level on top of any list queries. For example:

```
query MediaList($mediaIds: [ID!], $type: [MediaType!], $userId: ID!) {
  user {
    id
    medias_cursor(all_medias: true, active: true, ids: $mediaIds) {
      medias {
        id
        type
        category
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now for different MediaList query, the Media Objects might already exist in cache but we can not use it to skip network query. For example:
After we query `medias_cursor({"all_medias":true,"active":true,"ids":["361","362","363"]})`,
we've already got the three `Media` objects here - (`Media:361`, `Media:362`, `Media:363`).
So when we try to query `medias_cursor({"all_medias":true,"active":true,"ids":["361","363"]}`, we should have everything we need in the cache already. But right now, the apollo default behavior will just pass the cache and hit the network.

We tried to add a cacheRedirects config to solve this problem like this:

```
  const cache = new InMemoryCache({
    cacheRedirects: {
      User: {
        medias_cursor: (_, { ids }, { getCacheKey }) => {
          if (!ids) return undefined

          return {
            medias: map(ids, id => {
              return getCacheKey({ __typename: 'Media', id: id })
            })
          }
        },
      },
    },
  })
```

We are expecting that the cacheRedirects would help us to use the cache when it's available, but now it will skip the cache anyway.